# I have a problem that needs fixing with HTML on my website

Tags: html

Everything was working fine before, but it stopped working after a while. When I press the button to sign up, it opens up a blank page with a blank box, unlike before, when it had the actual stuff it was supposed to have. I have here the images, please help me. Thanks in advance!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8aC9.png)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Winit - Login/Sign Up</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/assets/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./src/main.css">
    <link rel="icon" href="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/7ytbxkmMme0IPSvsHZN9ZFd19oIZ9lqtq_402Z1UbIr0-1yMU_OoIbwaJsZ3x3ZEoQtZTJ4lR9hHLxSQibKiacHqfNyEEKdNunHv4J9hohCTtNlqO0yfb2rYGQhxl1M"
</head>
<body>
    <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
function SubForm(){
    $.ajax({
        url:'https://api.apispreadsheets.com/data/20789/',
        type:'post',
        data:$("#createAccount").serializeArray(),
        success: function(){
          alert("Form Data Submitted :)")
        },
        error: function(){
          alert("There was an error :(")
        }
    });
}
</script>
    <div class="container">
        <form class="form" id="login">
            <h1 class="form__title">Login</h1>
            <div class="form__message form__message--error">Incorrect Username/Password Combination</div>
            <div class="form__input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form__input" autofocus placeholder="Username or email">
                <div class="form__input-error-message"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="form__input-group">
                <input type="password" class="form__input" autofocus placeholder="Password">
                <div class="form__input-error-message"></div>
            </div>
            <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="remember" style="margin-bottom:15px"> Remember me
        <div>
            <button class="form__button" type="submit">Continue</button>
            <p class="form__text">
                <a href="#" class="form__link">Forgot your password?</a>
            </p>
            <p class="form__text">
                <a class="form__link" href="./" id="linkCreateAccount">Don't have an account? Create account</a>
            </p>
        </form>
        <form class="form--hidden" id="createAccount">
            <h1 class="form__title">Create Account</h1>
            <div class="form__message form__message--error"></div>
            <div class="form__input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form_input" input name="username" class="form__input" autofocus placeholder="Username">
                <div class="form__input-error-message"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="form__input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form__input" input name="email" autofocus placeholder="Email Address">
                <div class="form__input-error-message"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="form__input-group">
                <input type="password" class="form__input" input name="password" autofocus placeholder="Password">
                <div class="form__input-error-message"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="form__input-group">
                <input type="password" class="form__input" autofocus placeholder="Confirm password">
                <div class="form__input-error-message"></div>
            </div>
    <label>
           <button onclick="SubForm()" <button class="form__button" type="submit">Continue</button>
            <p class="form__text">
                <a class="form__link" href="./" id="linkLogin">Already have an account? Sign in</a>
            </p>
        </form>
    </div>
    <script src="./src/main.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: You have the button element repeated or wrong  ` <button onclick="SubForm()" <button class="form__button" type="submit">Continue</button>`

Comment: there were errors in your html, does this work on your site? https://pastebin.com/raw/nd24kez8

Comment: Thank you guys so much for the help. Sorry for asking about a simple problem, I'm still new to html.